# Chart.js with factory and webservices (Ionic)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, chart.js

I'm trying use Ionic Framework with AngularJS to build a mobile application.

I'm adding data from web services in my piechart with Chart.js.

My factory :

```
    .factory('SrvStatProduit', function($http) {
    var baseUrl = '';
    var statPro = [];
    //var baseUrl = 'http://webstock/api/';
    //var cmdAll = $http.get(baseUrl + '/api/stat/detail');
    return {
        all: function() {
            return $http.get(baseUrl + '/api/stat/detail');
        }
    };
})
```

My Controller :

```
.controller("PieCtrl", function ($scope,$http, SrvStatProduit, $stateParams) {

  SrvStatProduit.all().success(function(data) { 
    $scope.statPros = data;
    console.log(data);
    //Exemple with Pie Chart from Chart.js
    $scope.labels = ["Download Sales", "In-Store Sales", "Mail-Order Sales"];
    $scope.data = [data.QTE];
});
```

My HTML:

```
    <div ng-controller="PieCtrl">
    <div>
        <canvas id="pie" class="chart chart-pie" legend="true" data="data" labels="labels"></canvas>
    </div>      
</div>
```

I don't know how I can use my data from the web services. If I use `ng-repeat` in my html, if I will call data in the controller.

**Edit :**

First, thanks for your reply.

In my controller I have added this :

```
.controller("PieCtrl", function ($scope,$http, SrvStatProduit, $stateParams) {
SrvStatProduit.all().success(function(data) {   
    $scope.statPro = data;
    var x = new Array();
    for (var i = 1, len = $scope.statPro.length; i < len; i++) {
        $scope.data = [data[i].QTE];
        $scope.labels = [$scope.statPro[i].LIB_PROD];
    }
});
```

});

My pie chart add my data from web services but I only get the last data of the table.

How can I get all ?

Thank you

**Last Edit :**

The solution

```
.controller("PieCtrl", function ($scope,$http, SrvStatProduit, $stateParams) {
SrvStatProduit.all().success(function(data) {   
    $scope.statPro = data;
    var myArray = [];
    var myLib = [];
        for (var i = 1, len = $scope.statPro.length; i < len; i++) {
            console.log(i);
            myArray.push($scope.statPro[i].QTE);
            myLib.push([$scope.statPro[i].LIB_PROD]);
        }
        $scope.data = myArray;
        $scope.labels = myLib;
});
```

});

Thank you for your help ^^

Answer (score 0):

so if you are using $scope.statPros to hold your data and your data is a array of objects then I would also add your lables to statPros. so that each object has statPros.data object and a statPros.labels it would look like this:

```
[{data: {//data object}, labels: {//label object}}, {data: {//data object}, labels: {//label object}}]
```

in your html you can do

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in statPros">
            <canvas id="pie" class="chart chart-pie" legend="true" data="item.data" labels="item.labels"></canvas>
        </div>
```